# Proper way to use $.tmpl in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using tmpl in many places but I see a lot of repeats in my code like

```
$('#sel').html('');    // cleanup
$.tmpl('template', data).appendTo('#sel');
```

looks like I'm missing something, this should be possible with $.tmpl only. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `$('#sel').html($.tmpl('template', data))` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my view it is better to clean up first and then use

```
$.tmpl('template', data).appendTo('#sel');
```

Because jquery spec recommends it. Take a look at this piece of doc taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

> To insert the rendered template items into the HTML DOM, the returned
>   jQuery collection should not be inserted directly into the DOM, but
>   should be chained with .appendTo, .prependTo, .insertAfter or
>   .insertBefore